# How do you deploy a docker image into Cloud Foundry? [Bluemix]

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

Good morning,

I can't deploy a docker as cloud foundry app, when I run the following command:

```
cf push test-docker -o hello-world
```

> FAILED Error restarting application: Server error, status code: 400,
>   error code: 320003, message: Docker support has not been enabled.cf
>   enable-feature-flag diego_docker Entonces pruebo esto pero no me deja
>   activar el soporte a docker

So, then I ran this command:

```
cf enable-feature-flag diego_docker
```

> FAILED Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, message: You
>   are not authorized to perform the requested action

How can I do it?

What's the difference between the deployment on Cloud Foundry and a container? How do I do it?

A few weeks ago, I was able to do it, but now I don't find the way. Has something changed (apart from release DIEGO)?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

"The administrator for the CF installation you're targeting has disabled
docker support." ([source cloudfoundry.org mailing list](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/list/cf-dev@lists.cloudfoundry.org/message/4EH6UZLBTYB6HJW3VQAF7FILDDHA5FU7/))

Answer (score 0):

Review information doc to migrate your existing application running in DEA to Diego:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html#migrateapp

Cloud Foundry application runtime is not based on Docker runtime. For running a container application, you should start here:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html

Answer (score 0):

The diego_docker feature is not yet supported but will be in future in Bluemix.

In the meantime, I'd recommend using the [Bluemix container](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_integrations.html#container_cfapp_tutorial_intro).